# SQL order by using multiple columns using case

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

Table:

```
NUMBER DETAIL_ID,
Date schdeuledDate;
Date completedDate;
NUMBER recordId;
```

I am trying to implement this, retrieve records the most recent completed date and if null then most recent scheduled date and if more than one records retrieved then use higher recordId.

```
SELECT DETAIL_ID,completedDate,schdeuledDate,recordId FROM table
ORDER BY CASE completedDate WHEN NULL THEN schdeuledDate ELSE completedDate END,DETAIL_ID,recordId DESC;
```

But this what i get from the above query

```
Detail_ID  compdate     schdate    recordId
318        08-AUG-16    15-AUG-16   22342
318        06-JUN-18    22-AUG-18   26219
318        22-AUG-17    08-AUG-17   26218
418        null         08-AUG-17   26450
418        22-AUG-17    22-AUG-18   26879
418        22-AUG-17    22-AUG-18   26779
```

expected:

```
318        06-JUN-18    22-AUG-18   26219
418        22-AUG-17    22-AUG-18   26879
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by detail_id
                                order by coalesce(schdeuledDate, completedDate) desc, recordId desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```